# PDF of $\tfrac{aX}{b + cX}$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

> How to find the PDF of $$Y \triangleq \dfrac{aX}{b + cX},$$ where $a, b, c > 0$. Moreover, $X$ is a random variable with PDF given as $$f_{X}(x) = \dfrac{1}{\Omega} \exp \left( \dfrac{-x}{\Omega}\right); \quad x \geq 0, \Omega > 0$$

I have no idea, how to proceed. I'd be very much thankful if anyone can give any hint to proceed. Thanks!

**Edit**: Correction in $f_{X}(x)$ after getting the comment.

Comment: $1-e^{-x^2/\Omega}$ is not a pdf on the interval $0\le x$ since it approaches $1$ as $x\to\infty.$ Is this actually a c.d.f.? $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$\Pr\left(Y \le y\right)=\Pr\left(\frac{aX}{b+cX} \le y\right) = \Pr\left(X \le \frac{by}{a-cy}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: If $a>cy$. $ $ $ $

Comment: When we integrate this to find the CDF, the condition $a > cy$ can be violated. How do we solve in that case?

Comment: @user558929 Note that $$0 \le y = \frac{ax}{b+cx} < \frac{a}{c}.$$ The lower limit is achieved when $x=0$ and the upper limit when $x = \infty$. So $a > cy$.